# @future catch exception should be displayed in Vf Page

Tags: apex, future

My code is

```
public pagereference save(){
   //some code 
     for(integer i=0;i<10;i++){
         futureprocess(strl,i);
     }
     return null;
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void futureProcess(integer i,list<string> strlist){
    try{
       //some code
     }catch(exception e){
        if(apexpages.currentpage()!=null){ //this condition never satisfies
            ApexPages.Message errMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());  
                ApexPages.addMessage(errMsg);              
         }
     }
}
```

In catch block the condition never sets to true and hence unable to display the Error Message.Any Ideas on this

Comment: Use Javascript remoting instead .All the error will be reflected from server

Answer (score 3):

Future doesn't execute in the current context. Think of it as a lightweight batch process, it's asynchronously executed. You therefore CANNOT display error messages in the immediately returned page because the future method has been taken out of process and additionally is very unlikely to have been executed yet at that point.

You'll need to find an asynchronous strategy for error notification, like email or an alert infrastructure. Or not use future / batch.

Comment: Seconded. A common reason for using @future is because the call might take a long time and you don't want the user to wait. However in your case if there is relevant feedback that should be presented as a pagemessage in the event of failure then consider as jkray says removing the future annotation.